# Obtener todas las combinaciones de K elementos en un array

Tags: java, array

Lo que estoy buscando es un algoritmo que me permita obtener la suma todas las combinacions de K elementos en un array, por ejemplo:

En un array

```
    double array[] = {0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10};
```

Quiero la suma de K elementos, donde K = 2.

Ejemplo: ((0+2.5)/K),((2.5+5)/K), etc...

Salida (Sin repeticiones):

> (0, 1.5, 2.5, 3.75, 5, 6.25, 7.5, 8.75, 10)

Por ahora tengo esto:

```java
static ArrayList<Double> valores = new ArrayList<>();
    static double currentResult = 0;
    public static void obtener(double array[], int k, int indice) {



        if(k == indice){
            for (double d : array) {

                valores.add(d);
            }
            return;
        }


        for (int i = indice+1; i < array.length; i++) {

            if( i%(k-1) == 0){
                currentResult+=array[indice];
                currentResult/=k;
                valores.add(currentResult);
                currentResult=0;
            }
            currentResult+=array[i];

        }

        obtener(array, k, indice+1);

    }
```

Comment: Siento decirte que aqui no hacemos los deberes a las personas. Si quieres ayuda con algo en **concreto** adjunta el código que has intentado, lo que no te sale o las dudas que tengas.

Comment: Se me habia olvidado, ya lo puse

Comment: No termino de entender lo de "donde K elementos". Te refieres a la suma de todos los elementos hasta K? en donde si K es 2  seria la suma de 0 + 2.5+5?

Comment: K es el numero de subconjuntos del array a sumar. Si K = 3, entonces las sumas serian (0+2.5+5)

Comment: Yo tampoco llego a entenderlo. ¿Es la suma de cada elemento del producto cartesiano lo que buscas?

Comment: Es parecido a esta pregunta, pero en vez de imprimir las combinaciones, estoy tratando de hacer las sumas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n

Comment: El enunciado del problema es el siguiente: Tenemos 5 notas posibles en un examen (0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10), la variable k es el numero de examenes, mientras mas grande sea k, mas posibilidades de resultados hay. (Mis disculpas por los acentos, mi teclado no tiene)

Answer (score 1):

Creo que este código sirve para k=2. Se obtienen todas las posibles notas que podría haber.

```
public class ProductoCartesiano {

public static void main (String args []) {
    ProductoCartesiano.obtenerPC();

    System.out.println(ProductoCartesiano.valores);
}


static ArrayList<Double> valores = new ArrayList<>();

static double array[] = {0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10};

public static void obtenerPC () {

    //Número de elementos del producto cartesiano homogéneo Math.pow(array.length, k);

    for(int i= 0; i<array.length;i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<array.length; j++) {
                double valor = array[i] + array[j];
                if(!valores.contains(valor))
                valores.add(valor);
        }
    }

 }
}
```

Si quieres que k sea un número diferente de 2 habría que aplicar recursividad sobre un bucle for para que hubiese tantos bucles anidados como el valor de k. Ahora mismo no sé cómo hacer eso, tendría que darle unas vueltas. Espero te sirva.

**NOTA:** He puesto en un comentario cómo calcular el número de elementos que tendría el conjunto resultante en función de los elementos del conjunto inicial y de k.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias! Lo de los resultados repetidos se soluciona con un stream.

Comment: Puedes meter esta condicion antes de añadir el valor al arraylist `if(!valores.contains(valor))`. Edito la solución para que aparezca en contexto

Answer (score 0):

Voy a omitir la parte de la validación de que `K` este dentro del tamaño del Array proporcionado

Otra aclaracion es que en el ejemplo que has pasado :

> K = 3, entonces las sumas serian (0+2.5+5)

La suma seria 0+2.5+5+7.5 porque La posicion 0 existe en el array (no empieza en el 1), entonces si quieres los 3 primeros `K` debe ser 2

Un simple ejemplo de como podrias hacerlo :

```
    double array[] = {0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10};
    int K=4;
    double total =0;

    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
        total+= array[i];
    }

    System.out.println(total);
```